# Create application folder to be used by several users

Tags: c#, permissions, windows-services, appdata

I am creating a program that consists of a `(1) Windows Service` and a view `(2) WPF Application`. (the view and service do not have to be run at the same time) I will like to save all the settings on the same location. I was thinking to save all the settings on my application data directory. Because `(1)` and `(2)` are run by different users, `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` returns a different directory for each. How can I save both my wpf and windows service data on the same directory?

**When I initialize my wpf application I will like to read some of the files created by my windows service. where should my windows service write files so that my wpf application can see them?**

Comment: It's quite unusual to have a Service and a Desktop run on the same machine - in the corporate world this would be a no-no. So you'd need shared storage: either a network disk they can both access ot a database somewhere.

Comment: It's not unusual at all.  In our project, we take advantage of the fact that the service can be run at a higher elevation (Local System) than the application, which is generally restricted to user-level permissions.

Comment: I know I can create a WCF service but that will waste memory create more work form me where I just need to read a license key file when my wpf application starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want CommonApplicationData, instead, the "common repository for all application-specific data that is used by all users," as MSDN puts it under SpecialFolder.

However, there are at least [some cases](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a9b3e06-c53f-4e07-94a5-27786ddf7813/commonapplicationdata?forum=csharpgeneral) where permissions conflict, so make sure the ACLs are set correctly.

[This sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData) may help.